# Custom Module not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a beginner in iOS development. I cloned a repo containing working code. I opened up the project in xcode, but when I build the project I receive the error `Module 'Subscriptions' not found`.

In my build settings, the `Subscriptions.framework` framework is in Linked Frameworks and Libraries. From what I've researched about `module not found` errors in xcode, this should be the fix for my problem. However, this is not fixing my problem. This project should normally be able to be built and compiled. Is there something I'm missing here?

### Update

Here is the xcode file tree view.

```
Main
|-Main
|-MainTests
|-Products
|-Frameworks
|-Subscriptions.xcodeproj
  |-Subscriptions
  |-Products
    |-Subscriptions.framework
  |-Frameworks
|-Pods
Pods
```

Comment: You are not giving anywhere near enough detail about what "I cloned a repo containing working code" means, so one can only guess. What repo? Can we see it? What arrived when you cloned the repo? Is the framework there? Is it a target? Can you build it? Maybe the framework code itself is in a submodule?

Comment: Carthage dependency? CocoaPods dependency?

Comment: matt, the framework is it's own project with a target. I can build it successfully.

Comment: The framework is a separate project? But part of the same repo? So what is the repo? Two projects? A workspace? Is there a dependency? Are the search paths configured?

Comment: The repo seems to contain three projects. In the xcode file view, it seems like the `Susbcriptions` project is a submodule of the `Main` project. Then at the same level of the main project is a `Pods` project. I see the framework search path setting in the main project build settings. It seems to be set to the folder containing the framework of the `Subscriptions` project. I'm updating my question to include the file tree view shown in xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I finally figured out what was going on. I dove into the directory I thought that the `Susbcriptions.framework` was being installed in, and it wasn't there. The directory in the build products path was set to `Products/Debug-iphoneos` but the `Subscriptions.framework` was instead being installed into `Products/Debug`. This made me realize that somewhere in XCode I had the build setting set to build for MacOS instead of iOS. I found the setting and rebuilt my project for an iPhone XS simulator and the module was imported successfully.